# How can I use babel to transpile web source code and be able to deploy code on a server like the one provided by github?

Tags: javascript

**Hello and thank you for reading me.**

I would like to deploy the aplication to GitHub Pages web server.

However, when I try to use the JavaScript it reports:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

So then the Developer Tools reports that the errors are the imports:

```
    import CoreUtils from 'base/core/core.utils';
import LoadersVolume from 'base/loaders/loaders.volume';
import HelpersStack from 'base/helpers/helpers.stack';
import HelpersLut from 'base/helpers/helpers.lut';
import CamerasOrthographic from 'base/cameras/cameras.orthographic';
import ControlsOrthographic from 'base/controls/controls.trackballortho';
```

I have read that by defult Babel does not delete the imports and transpile the code.

I tried to fix it by myself reading:
[ES2015 import doesn't work (even at top-level) in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624819/es2015-import-doesnt-work-even-at-top-level-in-firefox)

[SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237388/syntaxerror-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-module)

[ES2015 module import and export syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336457/es2015-module-import-and-export-syntax-error)

Even:
https://github.com/framework7io/Framework7-Vue-Webpack-Template/issues/10

The fact is I have red the answers and some talk about editing the babelrc config file.

Somebody could help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can not just copy paste uncompiled code to be deployed:

1- Compile the example code:
`yarn dist:clean && yarn build:clean && yarn dist:ami && yarn dist:examples`

2- In the *dist* directory, find the example you are interested in

3- Deploy the example

Hope that helps...